# Android speech to text for robot control

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am thinking about making an app that I can use to control my Arduino robot (over bluetooth/wifi) using voice commands. But to make the experience fluid, I will need the Android app speech recognition to be continuously running. If I want the robot to stop, I don't want to press a button, wait for the speech recognition dialog to appear, say my command "STOP", release the button, wait for the parser to parse it, and then send the stop command.

I would rather just have the Speech to Text in continuous listen mode when I am controlling my robot. And when it hears keywords, it sends them.

Can I do this in Android? I did some googling, and I found the recognizer intent, but all of the examples I found use a button trigger and pretty much followed the scenario I described above.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. Look at this link. It has also some example code :)
You can make it listen and when it speeches you get the word see if it is a keyword and then make the robot do as you want.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/

Comment: I had seen that one before (it came up pretty high on my google search). But it uses a button to trigger the speech to text, and must individually parse each speech. I am looking for something that is continuously running, not requiring any user action. The engine would just spit out a constant stream of words that it is hearing, and when the app hears a keyword, then it will do stuff. Bottom line is, unless I am missing something, the code on that page will not work for me.